# Merge several rows to a single row with lists in the cells only if elements are different

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table:

```
source_system   geo_id  product_subfamily   product_deny_list   product_allow_list  transaction_deny_list   operation_allow_list    operation_filter
0   CONFIRMING_SCHF FRK CASH_MGMT   ' ' 'CNF'   ' ' ' ' NaN
1   EQUATION_SCHF   FRK CASH_MGMT   'CD','TEST','CB'    'CA'    '408','805','385','856','320','420','825','355...   ' ' NaN
```

I would like to convert it to this new table of one single row:

```
source_system   geo_id  product_subfamily   product_deny_list   product_allow_list  transaction_deny_list   operation_allow_list    operation_filter
0   [CONFIRMING_SCHF, EQUATION_SCHF]    FRK CASH_MGMT   ['CD','TEST','CB']  ['CNF', 'CA']   ' ' ' ' NaN
```

During the conversion, lists should be created in each cell only of the elements between the multiple rows are different, if they are the same, then, only the single value should be kept. If there was a blank string in a row and a value different from a blank string in the other row, the blank string should be removed and the other value kept.

How could i do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mini example of your data + solution:

```
d = {'source_system   ': ['CONFIRMING_SCHF ', 'EQUATION_SCHF'], 'geo_id': ['FRK', 'FRK']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_list = df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_list).T
```

Result:
[image: Result:]

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def apply_func(x):
    x = list(filter(None, set(x))) # Filter blank spaces
    if len(x) <= 1:
        return ''.join(x)
    return x

df = pd.DataFrame((['CONFIRMING_SCHF','FRK','CASH_MGMT', '', 'CNF' ,'','', np.nan],
                   ['EQUATION_SCHF','FRK', 'CASH_MGMT',   "'CD','TEST','CB'",'CA' ,  '408355','',np.nan]),
                  columns = ['source_system','geo_id','product_subfamily','product_deny_list','product_allow_list','transaction_deny_list','operation_allow_list','operation_filter'])
df['UNIQUE'] = 1
df_list = df.groupby('UNIQUE').agg(apply_func) #You can apply reset_index(drop=True) as well
df_list
```

This might be not proper solution for you because i have added additional column named as `UNIQUE`, but i am getting the output you expected, where you can apply almost all your conditions in the `apply_func` function

**Output**

```
source_system   geo_id  product_subfamily   product_deny_list   product_allow_list  transaction_deny_list   operation_allow_list    operation_filter
UNIQUE                              
1   [CONFIRMING_SCHF, EQUATION_SCHF]    FRK CASH_MGMT   'CD','TEST','CB'    [CNF, CA]   408355      [nan, nan]
```